# randomize a collection of domain objects

Tags: grails, random, groovy

I have a collection of domain objects (see image)

[image]

I've tried using `Collections.shuffle(responses)` but would not work on a cast type of Response. Is there a groovy way of randomizing these objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The screenshot shows a *set* of responses, and shuffle only works on lists. You'll have to copy the set into a list and then shuffle that:

```
def responsesList = []
responsesList.addAll(responses)
Collections.shuffle(responsesList)
```